# how do I decide which duplicate statistics should delete?

Tags: sql-server

I ran a query on SQL server that found duplicate statistics. As a result of this query, 1 record was returned. Under the AutoCreatedStatistics column it says "_WA_Sys_XX" and under the Index column it says "_dta_index_XX". As far as I understand, these two are duplicates. I want to delete 1 of them. But how do I decide which one I should delete? After making the decision, in order to delete statistics from SSMS, I need to hover over the statistics, right-click and look for the delete button, but the Delete button appears greyed out. Does anyone know why it looks gray?

Answer (score 6):

There’s a very high probability that no matter which one you delete, SQL Server will recreate it. If I were you, I would probably try to refocus my efforts on something that would solve a problem or improve circumstances for users of your database.

Comment: 100% agreement, but since one of those says "dta_" I'd sure drop that... and then stop running the DTA against the database.

Comment: dta = database tuning advisor

Comment: @GrantFritchey DTA is a four letter word, yes indeed.